# SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL' :

Tags: laravel

I am getting the same error with each and every wsdl url, that I have got as example while researching but am still getting the same error.

I have tried working with ssl and each and every suggestions seems to be a dead end as they do not resolve my issues.I have also set extension to openssl.

Here's the code I am using with Laravel.

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
        ini_set("default_socket_timeout", "300");
        ini_set ( 'max_execution_time' , 180);
        $opts = array(
            'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)
        );
        $params = array ('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'verifypeer' => false, 'verifyhost' => false, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1,'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient', "connection_timeout" => 180, 'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts) );
        $url = "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL";

        try{
            $client = new SoapClient($url,$params);
            dd($client->GetCitiesByCountry(['CountryName' => 'Peru'])->GetCitiesByCountryResult);
        }
        catch(SoapFault $fault) {
            echo '<br>'.$fault;
        }
```

This is the error that I am getting

SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL' :

I have tried more than 3 wsdl end points to check why the code is not working,but it seems that the my server is unable to connect to any of the host servers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a better description of the problem.  What errors do you get with the sample code you show?  Or if it runs but doesn't do what you expect, what did you get and what were you expecting.  And, save the description of how it makes you feel for the end (or just skip that part).

Comment: Hello sir, I have tried to describe it better. Please let me know I need to add something for getting this problem resolved.